# Searching for unsolved problems in the field of stability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, open-problem

I have proposed an approach for constructing Lyapunov functions for autonomous systems in my Ph.D. thesis and find some useful examples. Now, I am searching for some another example in this field or control theory (for autonomous systems), I will be grateful if propose me some examples or suitable references.

Comment: Isn't that your doctoral advisor's job? You can always take a look at [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=-OwmYdZySwAC).

Comment: Extend your approach to non-autonomous systems? Or to discrete systems, or systems with time delay, etc.?